# Facebook achievements

Tags: facebook-graph-api, achievements

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/

> Each achievement must possess a unique URL with the appropriate Open Graph protocol `<meta>` tags. We will scrape the achievement’s unique URL and use the information provided in the tags to generate the Ticker stories. The Ticker stories will redirect to the achievement’s unique URL.

**So each achievement simply needs an HTML file that has nothing but meta tags in it?**  That seems weird to me so I just want to confirm.  Since you still have to "create" the achievement  via an API call (different than awarding it to a user), I don't understand why that doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your question? If it's 'do i definitely need a page with the meta tags for Facebook's crawler?' the answer is 'Yes'

You can generate the tags programmatically via URL parameters, and can redirect any non-Facebook-crawler users that hit those URLs somewhere else if you want